# Why button click event triggered automatically on page load - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following is the sample code written in `React.js`.

> I am aware that passing the function to `onClick` event instead of
>   calling the function can resolve this issue.

But what I can't understand is why `onClick` event is triggered on page load itself and prompting the alert by invoking the `handleRemoveAll()` method. Is this due to `this.handleRemoveAll()` is invoked at the `global` context? I am trying to understand how `react.js` works.

```
class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
      const options = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
      return (
        <div>
            <Options options={options}/>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
class Options extends React.Component {
    handleRemoveAll() { 
        alert('Are you sure you want remove all?');
    };
    render() {
       return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleRemoveAll()}>Remove All</button>
                {
                    this.props.options.map((option) => <Option key={option} optionText={option} />)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<IndecisionApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: "onClick event is triggered on page load itself while calling the handleRemoveAll() directly" what does that mean? `alert` is being called the moment the page loads?!

Comment: Is this all of your code? I don't see a reason why `handleRemoveAll` would be called without a click happening.

Comment: I tried the same code and alert happens only on clicking. Please create a codepen link if u still have problem

Comment: @RohithMurali Please try it now.

Comment: @riwu Yes. I have edited the question for better understanding

Comment: Please see the below answer.

Comment: @RossAllen Please revisit my edited question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The onClick expects a function object, not a function call.
This is same as assigning a function Vs assigning its return value.

```
function foo(){
   return 5*5;
}
```

1)`var obj = foo;`
2)`var obj = foo();`

In case 1, you are assigning the function and in case 2 you are assigning the return value of foo(), ie, 25. So in case 2 like the above snippet the function will be called.

Comment: This solution is mentioned in my question itself. What my actual query is why `onClick` is triggered on page load when it is assigned with function call instead of function reference.

Comment: Please check the answer now.

Comment: So, Why that function has to be get fired on page load?

Comment: Becasue the onClick will be assigned with the object of the function when the page or element is loaded.

Comment: "So, Why that function has to be get fired on page load?" Because `render` gets called on page load, so `this.handleRemoveAll()` is also called.

Answer (score 0):

In reactJs if you write the function directly in component it means "this" keyword is refer to window. and that's why it's loading while page load.

So, try the below thing:

- make a constructor method into component and then bind the function which you created.
- And also use "this" keyword while making function.

I hope i did understood your question proper though you can try below suggestion or make clear your question.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
this.handleRemoveAll = this.handleRemoveAll.bind(this);
    this.handleRemoveAll = () => { 
        alert('Are you sure you want remove all?');
    };
}
```

Comment: "In reactJs if you write the function directly in component it means 'this' keyword is refer to window.." That's not quite true. What `this` refers to in JavaScript depends on how the function is called; this isn't because of React. Callback handlers are invoked in the global context, so `this` refers to the global context. `this` inside the OP's `render` method will be the component instance when `render` is called.